# Vue fails to render data object which has a parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need a JS tree object in which child nodes know who their parents are. Vue seems OK with this, at least as far as displaying the correct infinitely expandable object in Vue Devtools goes:

[image]

... and displaying the correct parent in the console:

[image]

The problem is that Vue errors when trying to render that data on a page:

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <b>family.name</b> {{ family.name }}
  </li>
  <li>
    <b>family.children[0].name</b> {{ family.children[0].name }}
  </li>
  <li>
    <b>family.children[1].name</b> {{ family.children[1].name }}
  </li>   
  <li>
  <!-- Add the extra brackets to this to see the "object" error -->
    <b>family.children[0].parent.name</b> { family.children[0].parent.name }
  </li>   
</ol>
```

**JS**

```
    var app = new Vue({
    el: '.container',
    data: {
        family: {
            name: "Dad",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Marcus",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Bob"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Anna",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Ringo"
                        }
                    ]       
                }           
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.family.children[0].parent = this.family;
        this.family.children[0].children[0].parent = this.family.children[0];
        this.family.children[1].parent = this.family;
        this.family.children[1].children[0].parent = this.family.children[1];
    }
  });
```

There is a live example if you prefer at https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mscau/vue-parenting.htm.

Does anyone know how to overcome this obstacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting up that relationship in [`mounted()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) lifecycle hook which occurs *after* the first render, so the render will fail before you even set this up.

If you do this work inside [`created()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) hook instead, it will set it up *before* the first render to avoid the failure.

See [lifecycle diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) for more detailed info about these hooks.

Comment: In addition, the `parent` property needs to be defined on each object upfront. Vue cannot detect property additions.

Comment: @DecadeMoon thank you for this great point. @MSC the solution to that comment is to put `parent: null` on your children objects so the property exists at the time Vue injects reactivity watchers.

Comment: I dont think you need to put anything except a condition that if parent is null dont render because of the above.

Comment: Thanks, all. WRT `parent: null`, I used to see that Vue needed to have the parent properties defined upfront as you suggest, but as you can see, it renders and reacts just fine without doing that: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mscau/vue-parenting-solved.htm

Comment: @MSC this is a happy accident because you are assigning `parent` to a reference Vue is already tracking